# php string formatting?

Tags: php, string, formatting

Here is the code

```
    $i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
    $output.="idno".$i."=".urlencode($row['usr_id']).
    '&'."res".$i."=".urlencode($row['responce']).
    '&'."sex".$i."=".urlencode($row['sex']).
    '&'."com1".$i."=".urlencode($row['com1']).
    '&'."com2".$i."=".urlencode($row['com2']);
     $i++;

    }
```

OUTPUT i get  idno is part of com2 string how do I seperate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an `&` when `$i` is not zero:

```
   $i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
    $output .= ($i ? '&' : '') . "idno".$i."=".urlencode($row['usr_id']).
        '&'."res".$i."=".urlencode($row['responce']).
        '&'."sex".$i."=".urlencode($row['sex']).
        '&'."com1".$i."=".urlencode($row['com1']).
        '&'."com2".$i."=".urlencode($row['com2']);
     $i++;

        }
```

Comment: Aaaah, that's what he meant. +1

Comment: Yeah, I had to read the question a few times to figure it out heh

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be using an array and join its elements afterwards:

```
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[] = "idno$i=".urlencode($row['usr_id']);
    $array[] = "res$i=".urlencode($row['responce']);
    $array[] = "sex$i=".urlencode($row['sex']);
    $array[] = "com1$i=".urlencode($row['com1']);
    $array[] = "com2$i=".urlencode($row['com2']);
    $i++;
}
$output .= implode('&', $array);
```

Furthermore you could use the *`argName`*`[]` declaration that PHP will convert into an array when receiving such a request query string.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do this:

```
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array["idno$i"] = $row['usr_id'];
    $array["res$i"] = $row['responce'];
    //etc.

    $i++;
}

$output = http_build_query($array);
```